# How to generate the patch ddl script (the delta/change script) for my spring container?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

My spring container is started with the property `auto-ddl=update` mode and the store that I am using `postgreSQl` gets updated as per the changes in my container every time I starts the container.

For example if I add an attribute to my `jpa entity`, my container will update my data base with new column corresponding to my new attribute.

My requirement is that ***I need this data base updates to be flushed into a file so that I can use it at a later point of time.***

I am aware of the hibernate property `javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action` which defines which scripts the persistence provider shall create.(none,create,drop-and-create,drop).

The above property will not give me a patch script but it gives full `ddl` scripts.

The thing is that the spring container along with hibernate is able to update my data base upon container start (I am able to see the alter scripts in my log file when `show-sql=true` is provided.) Hence this should be possible.

How can I generate the patch scripts ?